# Delete icon lateral and footer

Tags: css

How could I  delete icon from lateral and footer by Storefront woocomerce wordpress?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, take a few minute of your time to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for if you. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63979301/edit) your question with more details, informations, code, ...etc. Remember we're not next to you. For none-related code question visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your problem is purely CSS based. Without any type of code related to your issue or link to your website, nobody will be able to help you out.